# What does the Theodore doll say in Alvin and the Chipmunks?

Tags: plot-explanation, alvin-and-the-chipmunks

Near the end of the 2007 Alvin and the Chipmunks movie, the Theodore doll speaks Spanish (I think), and I still haven't been able to figure out what he says after watching the movie 30 times. I've worked out that Alvin's doll says "Hello, my name is Alvin, I want a hula-hoop" and Simon's says "My name is Simon". Do any Spanish speaking people know what Theodore says?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Theodore speaks Japanese. He should say something like that:

> **Konbanwa Watashi Wa** Theodore **desu**

that means "Good evening my name is Theodore". It's not pronounced very clearly, and most subtitles wrote **Alvin desu**, but listening to the voice it seems most likely to be Theodore. Maybe it's a Japanese name translation.

Comment: Funny then, because the Alvin doll says the same thing earlier in the movie, and Ian Hawke tells Dave that it's Spanish.

Comment: It's true. Ian says it's spanish but clearly you can hear **Kontawa Watashi Wa Alvin des**, thant IMO has nothing to do with spanish.

Comment: I believe the answer, I'm just saying that it's strange that they would make such a big mistake.

Comment: I think they deliberately made this mistake to make Ian seem like an ignorant/fool. You can see that Dave's face expression is not very convincing.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Watashi Wa means "I" in Japanese, Kon means "Good" while the second part would refer to the time of day like good morning, good afternoon, good evening, ext.. As far as des goes it's actually "Desu" and that's how you would end a sentence.

It is definitely Japanese.

Mata Ne (Bye/see you soon!)